# How to replace piecewise objective function in convex optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Suppose I have a minimization problem

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \min\limits_{x}
& & g(x)+f(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if}\ -1\leq x \leq 1 \\
      x^2, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

$g(x)$ is some convex function, $f(x)$ is loosely convex, and $g(x) + f(x) $ will still be strictly convex.

How to use some math magic to replace the if-else into something regular that an off-the-shelf convex solver can recognize?

Edit: To make sure $f(x)$ is convex

Comment: Your $f$ is not convex. It would be convex if you had $f(x)=1$ for $-1\le x\le 1$. Anyway, the definition of $f$ is already in mathematical form; what kind of definition does your "off-the-shelf convex solver" require?

Comment: For example, equality constraints and inequality constraints. There is no existing solver that I know of can handle if-else.

Comment: $\max \{1, x^2\}$

Comment: @dafinguzman How to further rewrite the max function into equality constraints or inequality constraints? Perhaps it is achievable by introducing another variable?

Comment: Yes, minimise $z$ and let $z$ be an upper bound to both functions inside the max.

Comment: Yes. please do write it up @dafinguzman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $f$ can be written as $\max\{1, x^2\}$. Minimising a maximum of two functions is equivalent to minimising an upper bound $z$ to both functions. The modified problem reads: Minimise $g(x)+z$ subject to the additional constraints $$z\ge 1,\quad z\ge x^2.$$

Comment: If possible, please do explain a bit more, including the details you gave in comment to the question.

Comment: @jessepfrancis Done!