# Dual with piecewise constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given the following minimization problem:

$$\begin{aligned}\min \quad & x \\ \mathrm{s.t.} \quad & f_1(x) \leq 0\end{aligned}$$

Where

$$f_1 = \begin{cases} -x + 2 &x\geq 1 \\ x  & -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\ -x -2 & x \leq - 1 \end{cases}$$

How would I go about finding the dual problem? I have been working at this for hours and cannot come up with anything.

Note: I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527966/how-to-replace-piecewise-objective-function-in-convex-optimization-problem) post but I don't think the solution applies here as $\max(-x + 2, x, -x -2) \neq f_1(x)$. If that were the case the solution would be trivial using epigraph form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition:
\begin{equation}
L(x,\lambda) = x + \lambda f_1(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
(1-\lambda)x + 2\lambda &\mbox{if } x\geq 1 \\ 
(1+\lambda)x  &\mbox{if } -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 
(1-\lambda)x -2\lambda &\mbox{if } x \leq - 1.
\end{cases}\end{equation}
The dual function is $g(\lambda) = \inf_x L(x,\lambda) \ \forall \lambda \ge 0$. Notice that if $\lambda \neq 1$ then let $x\to+\infty$ or $x\to-\infty$ we obtain $L(x,\lambda) \to -\infty$. When $\lambda=1$ it is easy to check that $\min_x L(x,1) = -2$, attained at any $x\le -1$. Therefore the dual function is
\begin{equation}
g(\lambda) =
\begin{cases} 
-2 &\mbox{if } \lambda = 1 \\ 
-\infty  &\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}\end{equation}
Obviously the maximum of $g(\lambda)$ is $-2$, attained at $\lambda = 1$.

Note that the problem is not convex because $f_1(x)$ is not convex (although it can be reformulated as a convex program), but it turns out in this case that strong duality holds.